# Current Site Time (in UTC) at Bottom of Every Page

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, timestamps

I'm sometimes confused by UTC and how it relates to the daylight savings time of my timezone. Could we get a little timestamp at the bottom of every page in UTC?

Comment: I'd rather not see this "feature", if you want to know what time UTC it is, check it online (see Jon's answer)

Comment: StackOverflow is not a clock. It's a Q&A Website.

Comment: But isn't a clock for answering questions like 'what time is it?'

Comment: It would be helpful to know when the page was generated.  Yes, usually you can refresh and get a new page, but I'd still like to know when a page was generated.  I have the same gripe about Google News; if I've disconnected, it would still be of interest to know when the page was last updated before I disconnected.

Comment: Related: [What time is it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79288/what-time-is-it)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why would we want to break caching for anonymous users every second of every day? :(

Beyond that, the UTC time is on your /recent page. Click the envelope at the top of the page and see.

edit: see the dropdown on your user name; it contains the current UTC time.

Comment: Could you avoid breaking caching by generating it at the client side? Presumably JavaScript has the notion of "current UTC time" doesn't it?

Answer (score 3):

Just remember it's 19:18 now

Answer (score 1):

You find the current UTC time in your [recent activity list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/recent/133268).

Answer (score 0):

Aside from anything else, you can always find the [current UTC time here](http://www.worldtimeserver.com/current_time_in_UTC.aspx).