# What time is it?

Tags: support, time

Where can I see the current server time on Stack Overflow?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32057/current-site-time-in-utc-at-bottom-of-every-page

Comment: And as an aside: all times have a tooltip showing the complete timestamp. Hence, hovering your mouse over text like "10 minutes" ago gives you some clue as well. (But: larger times, such as "2 hours ago", are less easy to interpret, due to rounding.)

Comment: Too bad the Stack Exchange Twitter account doesn't tweet questions from Meta. It would be funny if this became one of the hottest questions of the day.

Comment: @mmyers hahaha!

Comment: Four thirty.  It's not late.  It's early, early, early... and now I have Spin Doctors stuck in my head.

Comment: It's Friday in Iceland.

Comment: Related/Same: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62853/stack-exchange-sites-need-a-universal-clock-that-is-visible

Comment: Do you have the place?

Comment: @Rosinante: What? Did I miss a joke?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Click the "Recent Achievements" tab:

[image: screenshot of the UTC time in achievements dialog]