# How is the date calculated on the Stack Exchange websites?

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When does a day start?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27199/when-does-a-day-start)

It seems that the dates are calculated very strangely for the Stack Exchange sites.  I've been active on both Stack Overflow and Photo.StackExchange.com, and unless I log in around 7-9 am PST each day, I get a skip in the 'consecutive days' visiting the site.

When does the date roll over?  Is it Greenwich Mean Time, or some other time?  It definitely does not appear to be using a 24 hour timer, because I logged in at this same time yesterday and had something like 10 days running, and then logged in now and have 1 day running consecutively.

Answer (score 2):

Stack Exchange runs on [UTC](http://www.worldtimeserver.com/current_time_in_UTC.aspx). Merely being logged in doesn't count as "activity" -

> login pages, along with a number of other homepage style pages, don't count as "access").

References:

- [What time is it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79288/what-time-is-it)
- [Consecutive days problem #97?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66482/consecutive-days-problem-97)