# Is StackExchange going to fix its clock?

Tags: support

I am not sure, but I suspect that early this week, possibly even by Sunday, something changed at StackExchange.

I used to sometimes check my daily rep and if it is close to 200, to answer a few more questions close to 1pm.  However, I got caught out again as today, I noticed that when I hover over my username on stackoverflow.com at around 12:30pm, it was already showing

```
           today  week  month
reputation     0    x      x
revisions      0    0      0
favorites      0    x      x
```

What happened? Is the SE2 clock no longer synchronized to some universal source?

Comment: Daylight saving ended in Australia last weekend (or at least some parts of it). Maybe they're operating on Australian time.

Comment: @andrew all stack exchange sites run in UTC

Comment: As an aside: [What time is it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79288/what-time-is-it)

Comment: I should have put some smilies in the question... and maybe the fun tag

Comment: And maybe a space or two in the name Stack Exchange! ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Daylight saving time ended in New Zealand on this past Sunday. 00:00 UTC is now 12:00 (noon) local time. During the summer, 00:00 UTC is 13:00 local time.

This shift happens twice a year. Some people never get used to it.

Comment: +1 If this isn't the right answer, then @Ricahrd aka cyberwiki's profile is wrong