# What's the server time?

Tags: support, stack-exchange

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What time is it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79288/what-time-is-it)

I'm not exactly sure if there's question about it, if yes, execuse me.

Can I find server time of SO & other SE sites?

Comment: Hover over the words "Asked 3 mins ago" right above your name. :P

Comment: put it as answer please :) -2 hours from me :p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see the UTC time when you hover over the dropdown at the top of the page (see screenshot):

[image]

Here's a handy link to see the time that the Web Server might actually be in ([The Web Servers live in New York](http://blog.serverfault.com/post/1432571770/)):

http://www.worldtimebuddy.com/?lid=5128581,0&h=0

screenshot:

[image]