# UTC timezone message on reputation count page

Tags: feature-request, timestamps

If we can add a message in reputation saying something like based on UTC timezone reputation is distributed to Today/1 Day etc., tags will avoid confusion for the people who are far away from UTC timezone. In my case it happened that at 7PM EST my reputation count changed to today and 1 day.

Comment: Though I guess many people who might *expect* the time to be in their own time zone (that is: folks from the USA, this being a USA-based site) are quite used to time zone differences [in their own very country](http://www.worldtimezone.com/time-usa12.php), I'd also say: why not! And related: [What time is it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79288/what-time-is-it)