# Reputation is being added for the wrong day

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What time is it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79288/what-time-is-it)

It is currently 15:52 where I live.  Yet I have numerous upvotes that occurred more than 15 hours ago ([12 to be exact](https://stackoverflow.com/users/672118/dunsmoreb?tab=reputation)) that are being categorized under the today tab.  While I'm not sure if this is messing up my reputation calculations, why is this?

Comment: All times in SO are UTC time.  It's currently like 9 PM UTC I think.

Comment: This shouldn't affect it though as the upvote times would be `UTC - x` hours ago.

Comment: The current UTC time is displayed in the panel that drops down when you hover over your username. It's 20:58 right now. The votes you're talking about seem to have been cast between 16 and 20 hours ago, which does match the current UTC day.

Comment: Argh.  I hate time zones.

Comment: @PopularDemand: Actually its 21:02 right now, your UTC clock seems to be slow.